How to make from html.parser.HTMLParser print raw input?
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag, attrs)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<strong>&lt;h3&gt; &lt;u&gt;OPINION&lt;/u&gt; &lt;/h3&gt;</strong>')

The above program shows the following output.
Encountered a start tag: strong []
Encountered some data  : <h3> <u>OPINION</u> </h3>
Encountered an end tag : strong

But I want <h3> <u>OPINION</u> </h3> be the original input as &lt;h3&gt; &lt;u&gt;. How can I achieve this to keep the original input data?
